# Como criar trigger postgre

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em relação a tabela acima,

1)  Crie uma trigger que a cada registro inserido na tb_movimentacao, o saldo da conta seja atualizado em tb_saldo. Lembrando que se o lançamento for do tipo ‘C’ aumenta o saldo, caso for do tipo ‘D’ diminui o saldo – (procedimento valido para todas as triggers a serem criadas) 
2)  Crie uma trigger que a cada alteração no campo Valor no registro de tb_movimentacao, o saldo seja automaticamente atualizado em tb_saldo;

Alguém consegue me ajudar? haha

Comment: acredito que o pessoal daqui não curte esse negocio de colar enunciado de tarefas para simplesmente ter a resposta não... dá uma lida na documentação e veja se te ajuda: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criando Estrutura de Tabelas:

```
-- CLIENTE
CREATE TABLE tb_cliente
(
    id BIGINT,
    nome TEXT
);

-- MOVIMENTACAO
CREATE TABLE tb_movimentacao
(
    id BIGINT,
    id_cliente BIGINT,
    tipo VARCHAR(1),
    valor REAL
);

-- MOVIMENTACAO
CREATE TABLE tb_saldo
(

    id_cliente BIGINT,
    valor REAL
);
```

Criação da `Trigger Function`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fc_atualizar_saldo()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    n REAL DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN
    IF( NEW.tipo = 'D' ) THEN
        n = NEW.valor * (-1);
    ELSIF( NEW.tipo = 'C' ) THEN 
        n = NEW.valor;
    END IF;

    IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM tb_saldo WHERE id_cliente = NEW.id_cliente ) THEN
        INSERT INTO tb_saldo ( id_cliente, valor ) VALUES (  NEW.id_cliente, n );
    ELSE
        UPDATE tb_saldo SET valor = valor + n WHERE id_cliente = NEW.id_cliente;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Criação da `Trigger`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_atualizar_saldo AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON tb_movimentacao FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fc_atualizar_saldo();
```

Teste - Cadastro Clientes:

```
INSERT INTO tb_cliente ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 1, 'JOAO' );
INSERT INTO tb_cliente ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 2, 'MARIA' );
INSERT INTO tb_cliente ( id, nome ) VALUES ( 3, 'FULANO' );
```

Teste - Recupera o Saldo de todos os Clientes cadastrados **antes** das Movimentações:

```
SELECT 
    c.id,
    c.nome,
    COALESCE( s.valor, 0.0 ) AS saldo
FROM
    tb_cliente c
LEFT JOIN
    tb_saldo AS s ON ( s.id_cliente = c.id );
```

Saída:

[image: antes]

Teste - Simula movimentações do Cliente "JOAO":

```
INSERT INTO tb_movimentacao ( id, id_cliente, tipo, valor ) VALUES ( 1, 1, 'C', 1000.00 ); -- Saldo: +1000.00
INSERT INTO tb_movimentacao ( id, id_cliente, tipo, valor ) VALUES ( 2, 1, 'D', 10.75 ); -- Saldo: +989.25
INSERT INTO tb_movimentacao ( id, id_cliente, tipo, valor ) VALUES ( 3, 1, 'D', 22.50 ); -- Saldo: +966.75
INSERT INTO tb_movimentacao ( id, id_cliente, tipo, valor ) VALUES ( 4, 1, 'C', 100.00 ); -- Saldo: +1066.75
INSERT INTO tb_movimentacao ( id, id_cliente, tipo, valor ) VALUES ( 5, 1, 'D', 1000.00 ); -- Saldo: +66.75
```

Teste - Simula movimentações da Cliente "MARIA":

```
INSERT INTO tb_movimentacao ( id, id_cliente, tipo, valor ) VALUES ( 1, 2, 'C', 1000.00 ); -- Saldo: +1000.00
INSERT INTO tb_movimentacao ( id, id_cliente, tipo, valor ) VALUES ( 2, 2, 'C', 200.00 ); -- Saldo: +1200.00
INSERT INTO tb_movimentacao ( id, id_cliente, tipo, valor ) VALUES ( 3, 2, 'D', 500.00 ); -- Saldo: +700.00
INSERT INTO tb_movimentacao ( id, id_cliente, tipo, valor ) VALUES ( 4, 2, 'D', 100.00 ); -- Saldo: +600;00
INSERT INTO tb_movimentacao ( id, id_cliente, tipo, valor ) VALUES ( 5, 2, 'D', 10.00 ); -- Saldo: +590.00
```

Teste - Recupera o Saldo de todos os Clientes cadastrados **depois** das Movimentações:

```
SELECT 
    c.id,
    c.nome,
    COALESCE( s.valor, 0.0 ) AS saldo
FROM
    tb_cliente c
LEFT JOIN
    tb_saldo AS s ON ( s.id_cliente = c.id );
```

Saída:

[image: depois]